# Web API, authenticate using Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

We have an Angular SPA and Web API which is hosted in IIS - standalone server.

Our Web API uses user ID and password OAuth token authentication.

One of our client wants to use their Azure AD instead of our application's user id and password.

How to pass their AD token in our `/token` API call? Is there any easy way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by two ways.

Approach 1# using ADAL.js in SPA

For SSO Clients
Get AD Token using ADAL, then pass it to /token with custom grant_type and  decrypt AD token and generate your own token

Apporach 2# using SAML approach

For SSO Clients
Get SAML response, and pass it to /token with custom grant_type and  decrypt SAML token with certificate you received from AD SSO then generate your own token